# Using icons in <li> and have separate properties?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a navigation using li with little icons next to the text. I managed to get it working but how can i edit the properties of `<li>` like color, padding etc.

If i change the padding of .homeicon it moves the little icon about. Is there a way to have all the main properties under li then just the icon under .homeicon?

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PFQke/45/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li class="homeicon"><a href="">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation {
    margin:14px;
    height:80px;
}
#navigation li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline;
    margin-left:15px;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         4px 4px 9px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75); 
}
#navigation .homeicon {
    background: url("images/home.png") no-repeat top left;
    padding: 3px 0px 4px 25px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change where the icon actually is to the child of `<li>` like:

```
#navigation .homeicon a {
  }
```

And style that element as you styled the old `#navigation .homeicon {`. Then the changes to `<li>` won't affect *directly* to the icon itself.

Note: I changed the icon so I could see a visual representation of it

> http://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/PFQke/47/

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean now, Thanks alot worked great.

Comment: Uhm, I wasn't sure if I completely understood the original question and now I'm even more confuse. You can even do `#navigation li:first-child a {}` or simply change the class to the a and then do `#navigation li .homeicon`, if that's what you mean...